# "if instr" not working with a loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am a VBA beginner. I am trying to build a macro that would copy and paste (value) an entire row to a new sheet based on a differentiation criteria. The differentiation criteria, in this case, would be the content of specific cell. In other words, if the cell contains the word "Caviar" then copy the row into sheet 1 otherwise copy into sheet 2. The following macro works when I run it manually (row one by one).

```
Sub Search_and_copy()
Dim rng As String
rng = Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value
Dim rowNo As Integer
rowNo = 6
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = Sheets("40").Range("P11").Value

        rowNo = 6
        If Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value = "254" Then
                If InStr(celltxt, "CAVIAR") Then
                    Rows("11:11").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                    If IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1)) Then
                            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Else:   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1))
                                rowNo = rowNo + 1
                            Loop
                            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    End If
                    Sheets("40").Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Else
                    Rows("11:11").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                    If IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1)) Then
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Else:   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1))
                                rowNo = rowNo + 1
                            Loop
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    End If
                    Sheets("40").Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

                End If
        End If

End Sub
```

However, as soon as I introduce a loop (see code below), the differentiation is no longer properly made and all rows are copied into the same worksheet. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Search_and_copy()
Dim rng As String
rng = Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value
Dim rowNo As Integer
rowNo = 6
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = Sheets("40").Range("P11").Value


    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value)

        rowNo = 6
        If Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value = "254" Then
                If InStr(celltxt, "CAVIAR") Then
                    Rows("11:11").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                    If IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1)) Then
                            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Else:   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1))
                                rowNo = rowNo + 1
                            Loop
                            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    End If
                    Sheets("40").Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Else
                    Rows("11:11").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                    If IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1)) Then
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Else:   Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1))
                                rowNo = rowNo + 1
                            Loop
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    End If
                    Sheets("40").Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

                End If

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Why `Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value)`? You cannot just add a loop to recorded macro, since recorded macro uses absolute address, and you did nothing to move on to next row/column.

Comment: Since everytime I delete the row that I copy, I don't need to indicate the macro to move to the next row. As a matter of fact, the table will "move up" and the if condition will always be checked in the same cell (F11). From what I understood from my different trials, I think the macro checks the if condition only for the first loop and then it copies automatically the rest of the table into the same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The (first) problem is that you never change the value of `celltxt` inside your loop. After you read `Sheets("40").Range("P11").Value` into the string, you never change it.  This means that `InStr(celltxt, "CAVIAR")` will always be the same until the Sub ends. All you should need to do is update it inside your loop.

One other thing to do while you're at it is to apply a little [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and extract your common code into a function.  The only difference between your `If` and `Else` is the sheet name.  Try something like this:

```
Sub Search_and_copy()
    Dim celltxt As String

    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value)
        celltxt = Sheets("40").Range("P11").Value
        If Sheets("40").Range("F11").Value = "254" Then
            If InStr(celltxt, "CAVIAR") Then
                DontRepeatYourself "Sheet1"
            Else
                DontRepeatYourself "Sheet2"
            End If
        End If
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub DontRepeatYourself(sheet As String)
    Dim rowNo As Long
    rowNo = 6
    Rows("11:11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(sheet).Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowNo, 1))
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
    Loop

    Sheets(sheet).Cells(rowNo, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                           SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("40").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution as well as the explanation. It works perfectly. I will also take into consideration your advice regarding the rationalization of the code.